# awk with zero output

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have four column and I would like to do this:
INUPUT=

```
429 0   10  0
287 115 89  64
0   629 0   10
542 0   7   0
15  853 0   12
208 587 5   4
435 203 12  0
604 411 27  3
0   232 0   227
471 395 5   5
802 706 15  15
1288    1135    11  23
1063    386 13  2
603 678 7   14
0   760 0   11

awk '{if (($2+$4)/($1+$3)<0.2 || ($1+$3)==0) print $0; else if (($1+$3)/($2+$4)<0.2 || ($2+$4)==0) print $0; else print $0}' INPUT
```

But I have error message :

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=3) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

Even if I have added condition:

```
...|| ($1+$3)==0...
```

Can somebody explain me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much.

PS: `print $0` is just for illustration.

Comment: You are saying `.... / ($1+$3)` and in some cases both `$1` and `$3` are 0, so you are dividing by zero.

Comment: The added condition cannot make a difference because the division by zero happens when the first statement is evaluated. The second one would only be evaluated if the first one wasn't true. A fatal error is not a false value but an immediate exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the "($1+$3) == 0" to be the first clause of the if statement. Awk will evalulate them in turn. Hence it still attempts the first clause of the if statement first, triggering the divide by zero attempt. If the first clause is true, it won't even attempt to evaulate the second one. So:-

```
awk '{if (($1+$3)==0 || ($2+$4)/($1+$3)<0.2) print $0; else if (($1+$3)/($2+$4)<0.2 || ($2+$4)==0) print $0; else print $0}' INPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already dividing by zero in your conditional statement ($1+$3=0 on the ninth line of your list). That's where the error comes from. You should change the ordering in your conditional statement: first verify that $1+$3!=0 and only then use it to define your next condition.